Randomly moving blue bar in VisualStudio
I have been struggling with Visual Studio lately. For some reason, a blue bar with code from the current document appeared on the top of the document editor.
This happened in both Community edition and preview.
Does anyone have the same experience?


I guess it's because these lines are folded.
